# Computing the derivative

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

Denote the set of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries by $\mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$. Given two $n \times n$ matrices $A = ((a_{ij}))$ and $B = ((b_{ij}))$, their dot product is defined as the sum of the products of corresponding entries: $A \cdot B = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}b_{ij}.$ Consider the determinant function $\Delta: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. Show that for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, the derivative of this function at $A$ is given by $D_{A}\Delta(V) = A^{\ast}\cdot V$ where $A^{\ast}$ is the matrix of cofactors: the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^{\ast}$ is the $(i,j)$ cofactor of $A$.

Firstly, this is the first of two parts of my HOMEWORK problem. The second part of this problem was to show that the derivative of the determinant at the identity matrix is the trace of $V$. I was able to do that problem because the algebra isn't really that messy when I use the definition of a directional derivative. But I cannot get that formula for the problem I asked, there has to be some clever trick. Can anyone help me with first step?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, probably by $A\cdot B$ actually $tr(AB)$ is meant. I will leave it to you to prove that $D_{I}\Delta(V)=tr(V)$ as it is an instructive exercise. The hint for this is just to look at $det(I+tV)-det(I).$

We calculate $D_A\Delta$ in two steps. First, we assume that $A$ is invertible. Then:

$det(A+tV)-det(A)=det(A)[det(I+tA^{-1}V))-det(I)].$

Thus $D_A\Delta(V)=det(A)tr(A^{-1}V)=tr(A^*V)$

Finally, we prove it for general $A$. The point is that the set of invertible matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. We look at the map $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\mathbb{R})$ defined by $A\mapsto D_{A}\Delta(V)-tr(A^*V). $

By the considerations above considerations and the continuity of this map we conclude that it is always $0$, which is what we needed to prove.